# No “$” or “#” Sign After Logging in Solaris 10 with Putty

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, solaris, solaris-10

This is my environment :

Solaris Version 10; Sun OS Version 5.10 Oracle Version: 11g Enterprise x64 Edition.

When I am getting log on through putty it is giving me this output:

login as: ora Using keyboard-interactive authentication.

Password:

Last login: Sun Nov 2 10:24:21 2014 from abc

It is not showing "$" sign or anything.. I cant write on it but cannt execute linux command or get any output from it. I have even logged in by root password and yet still same. Can I one descirbe me this to me and guide this matter.

My Oracle Based Database is running on it and I dont want to restart my server. So how can I fixed it and get $ or # ??

Comment: @choroba...

sorry ??
I didnt get it..

Comment: @choroba He posted on SO, was told that it was the wrong place, so he reposted here. What's your point? I guess he should have deleted the original, too.

Comment: Does this only happen when you login using SSH, or also when you login on the console? It sounds like a problem with one of your shell startup scripts. If it happens to multiple accounts, it maybe `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. This will make them show all the commands as they're executing, and you can see where it hangs.

Comment: @Barmar..

Yes..
But how can put set -x at the beginning of /etc/profile and ~/.profile when its not executin any commands when I am writing on it...

Comment: When I am logging through Serial it give this:


Nov  2 12:13:12 hooradb2 scsi: WARNING: /pci@1f,700000/pci@0/pci@2/pci@0/pci@8/LSILogic,sas@1/sd@3,0 (sd5):
Nov  2 12:13:12 hooradb2        Error for Command: read                    Error Level: Retryable
Nov  2 12:13:12 hooradb2 scsi:  Requested Block: 1632                      Error Block: 1632
Nov  2 12:13:12 hooradb2 scsi:  Vendor: SEAGATE                            Serial Number: 071891XA2J
Nov  2 12:13:12 hooradb2 scsi:  Sense Key: Aborted Command
Nov  2 12:13:12 hooradb2 scsi:  ASC: 0x8 (LUN communication time-out), ASCQ: 0x1, FRU: 0x81

Comment: That sounds like you're having disk errors.

Comment: Yes I know that.
I have four hard-disks in my SunServer,how can I know which hard-disk has OS in this current situation ??

Comment: It looks like you're not getting a TTY when you log in. Could you edit your question to include the exact `ssh` command that you're running to make this connection? Feel free to obscure the hostname & username if you like. Also, what shell does this user have on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll almost certainly be looking at a failure during the login process.  Something is hanging and preventing you from reaching an interactive shell.

Try the following tricks to get back in:

- Log in as a different user / find someone else on the server with a
  login, then `su <your username>` (note the lack of '-' in su, this
  skips the target user's environment)
- Log in as root / ask the sysadmin to edit your profile for you as root
- Connect via `ftp` or `ftps`
- Try your luck via a non-interactive link like `scp`, `rsync -e ssh`, or `sftp`

Provided one of these tricks gets you access and you get an interactive shell, you should then move aside your profile files:

`mkdir broken-profile-files ; mv .profile .bashrc .login .cshrc .bash_profile broken-profile-files`

If you have a non-interactive shell via something like ftp, use `ls` or `ls -a` to identify any profile files and either move or delete them (typically `rename` or `delete`)

If you can get in via something like rsync, you can backup the current version of the files first by doing an rsync pull, then push an empty file back up to overwrite it.

Once you are back in and running with an empty profile do the following to debug:

- Open a new shell, leave it open, don't touch it, don't close it.  In fact, open two, why not?  This will be your "get out of jail free" card.
- Now copy back your profile files one by one, attempting to login via a new window each time until you get the problem back
- Either add set -x to the top of the file that's giving your trouble or throw a few `echo "Here"` lines in it to track how far through you get before it freezes
- Identify the issue and debug/prune as required

Probably causes of a hang:

- Attempting to explore a directory tree that's invalid or stale (eg shell expansion of * on a stale NFS mount of autohome directory)

One last thought: There's also the possibility that you have a larger fault in one of the global config files, in which case I'd recommend you just come up in single user mode and fix it that way.

Comment: I have resolved the issue.

The server was on hang state due to hardware failure. I let it remained logged in for more than 30 mins & it got the terminal.

But thanks for the suggestions  , they where really really helpful and exactly what I was looking for !!

Thanks again !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

The server was on hang state due to hardware failure. I let it remained logged in for more than 30 mins & it got into the terminal.

But thanks for the suggestions especially Smiling Dragon!!